# How to design an OLTP system?

Tags: sql, database-design

Take retail store as an example: if a customer purchased total 30 items (not necessarily 30 different items) in one transaction, how to design the sales table to record this transaction? 
Should it be one row (with one unique transaction ID) to record all details of each item purchased, or we should have multiple rows (with same transaction ID) to record each specific items purchased in the same transaction? Thanks!

Comment: Hey, I have written my answer. Give your thoughts.

Comment: Thanks so much Ali! This is great. The scenario you presented is exactly what I was asking for. Another question: how to handle return. I assume return some purchased items in a previous transaction will have a different transaction ID associated with it. If this is the case, how to link the two transactions together? Should we separate purchase (sold in your example) and return in two different tables and use foreign key(s) to link them together? Thanks again!

Comment: I would love if you could up-vote and select as solution. For any other questions, open up a new SO post. You're welcome buddy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider each sale of an item a specific transaction, then having multiple transactions can be one idea, but if you consider a batch of item sales in one go by a single person to be regarded as a single transaction, then I would personally have three tables.

Here's an example to show this. Note that it is always a good idea to minimize redundancy using normalization principles. Also note that primary keys `tid,itemid` in the Sold Table will form a super-key in this instance, as they uniquely identify a record in the database.

I am hoping you have a basic concept of superkeys, primary keys and foreign keys and the general workings of how relational database management systems work. By the way, you need a more robust design for this to work in the real world.

**Transaction Table**

This table will have the list of all the unique transactions identified by `tid`.

Further more, this table will also have columns for `person, time, store, cashier` etc.

**Item Table**

This table would have a list of all the items (`itemid`) available for sale.

Further more, this table will also have columns for `item name, item quantity, type` etc.

**Sold Table**

This table would have `tid`, `itemid` and `quantity`.

This way you can uniquely identify which transaction sold which items. Obviously, this is for a relational database system (RDBMS). There are many ways to approach this, depends on your design and needs.

A sample example which exhibits minimal redundancy:
[image]